# Explain massive performance difference in html canvas image drawing

Tags: performance, canvas

While investigating some performance issues I stumbled upon the following performance comparison:

http://jsperf.com/fastest-canvas-drawing/2

which yields the following result:

[image]

This seems to suggest that if you use anything but a `createObjectURL` image drawImage will be more than 90% slower. Is this really the case? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run this test in Chrome, Safari or another WebKit?

`window.URL` is undefined in Chrome, you'd need to use `window.webkitURL` instead (although [not anymore in Chrome 23](http://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls), but the use of `mozGetAsFile` kills you anyway). You're seeing such faster results because the tests are just erroring out under Chrome for that option.

On Firefox, the results are much more in line with one another, as you might expect.

Comment: As visible on the screenshot I ran it on Chrome but I also tried it in IE10 and got similar results.

Comment: I only have IE 9 which also doesn't have `window.URL`, but I'd bet it's just the same `mozGetAsFile` problem again. You probably have an error somewhere on that page to that effect. It's really just a somewhat old test that, at this point, really only works correctly on Firefox.

Comment: I see, thanks for that. Should've checked the source rather than just looking at the results.